What is better - #href-sections or /page-names
I have a one page site. The template I got uses JavaScript, and when someone clicks the top navigation, it scrolls to that section.
Now, I was thinking of adding JavaScript to change the Windows.location to change the URL when they click one of the buttons. Here is an example:
https://www.therafaelbk.com/#floorplans
The only real advantage I can see to doing this is that it lets the user bookmark a section of the site, rather than just the entire site. Is there any advantage to SEO (or disadvantage), and do I need to use #anchors, or can I use straight URLs (/pricing, /about-us, ect)
Does anyone have a tutorial on how to do this? I tried to figure it out from the example in this post, but it looks like that code was generated by some kind of editor.
This almost does what I want, but it only updates when the user clicks. I want to update the browser url when the user scrolls with the mouse. So, if you scroll to the "Contacts" header, the url turns to /Contacts
Is this good for SEO, or is it better to use #achors? I'm afraid the search engines will see every page (/Contact, /About, ect) as just a copy of the index page. If 5 URLs all point to the same thing, doesn't that hurt SEO?
I can not figure this out. I tried to add an event that fires when the scroll is completed:


 $(".navbar-nav > li").click(function (event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 var target = $(this).find(">a").prop("hash");
  $("html, body").animate( {
    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top,
    complete: function () { alert("x"); }
  ,
 }, 500 ); });



But it never fire the complete event. I thought maybe main.js was cached and not refreshing, but I moved the code right into the body and the complete event still never fires. Any ideas?
I want it so that, when the scroll completes, the url updates to /#section
That way someone can bookmark a specific section. It'd be nice if they could mouse scroll and it would update the url bar too.

I can not figure this out. I tried changing the function in main.css to add an oncomplete:
$(".navbar-nav > li").click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var target = $(this).find(">a").prop("hash");
$("html, body").animate(
{
scrollTop: $(target).offset().top,
complete: function () {
alert("x");
},
},
500
);
});
